# Make my screen flash

Tags: ios, animation

I know this question has been asked on here before but I just can't get it to work.  I want to get my screen to flash white when I run the method -(void)flashScreen.  I have gone through many pages and tutorials and they are all using a similar method to what I have shown in my code below:

```
-(void) flashScreen{

    flash.alpha = 0.0;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0];
    flash.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I have tried using other methods aswell such as:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                      delay:0.0
                      options:0                     
                      animations:^{
                     flash.alpha = 1.0;
                    }
                  completion:nil];
```

But this doesn't do anything either.  I have imported the UIKit framework, the QuartzCore framework.  What am I missing?

Please help!  And thank you in advance!

Comment: What is flash?  Is it a white UIView that covers the whole screen?  What happens if you set flash.alpha to 1.0 without animations?  Does your screen go white?  Get that working first.

Comment: A flash is a UIImageView.  It is just an image which is white and covers the whole screen.  When I change the alpha of the image, it does change so I know thats working.  However, when I try to use the animation above, the 'flash' just sits on the alpha I set before and doesn't change.  Thanks!